# Or in querying mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to query my records using OR and based on mongoDB doc [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html),

Example from doc:

```
{
  title:"MongoDB",
  $or:[
    {author:"Daniel"},
    {author:"Jessica"}
  ]
}
```

My code:

```
Model.Entity.find({
    $or:[
        {type: 1},
        {type: 2},
        {type: 3},
    ]
}).exec(callback);
```

It returns me empty list although there are records with type 3.

What could be wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you update your question to show an example document that you're expecting this to return? Also, it would be more efficient to use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) instead of `$or` here.

Comment: please list all of your concerning code

Comment: the doc includes `$or` as it's property? I don't understand. you don't have a `type` property at all, what did you expect to find?

Comment: Please gives to us the schema of the concerned collection.